# Does compact normal space implies metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, separation-axioms

I know compact Hausdorff space is normal, and metric space is normal.

What about compact normal space? Is it a metric space?

My naive guess is that normality is nothing to do with metric and compactness(finiteness) is also nothing to do with metric so it seems it is not a metric space. But how one can prove or disprove this more than my idea?

Comment: What about $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ with product topology?

Comment: Not necessarily, since any compact space is normal.

Comment: Some examples [here](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=compact%20%2B%20normal%20%2B%20~metrizable)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . Also $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]},$ with the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A beautiful example to the contrary is the [Double Arrow Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval), one of the classics in topology.

It's compact, perfectly normal ($T_6$), hereditarily Lindelöf, hereditarily separable, first countable, but not metrisable as it does not have a countable base.

Comment: Another elementary example is the lexicographic-order topology on $X=[0,1]^2$. All linear spaces are normal, and $X$ has the $lub$ property (every subset has a $lub$) so $X$ is compact. A compact metrisable space is separable, but $\{\{r\}\times (1/3,2/3):r\in [0,1]\}$ is an uncountable family of pairwise-disjoint open subsets of $X,$ so $X$ is not separable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet double arrow is a subspace of that square. But it’s nicer ( hereditarily separable/ Lindelöf).

Comment: Yes.  The lex. square is not $T_6$, among other things. The Double-Arrow is a great example of how far you might go and still not be metrisable.